# Javascript : What are the different conditions when javascript work in IE but not in Firefox or some other browser?

Tags: javascript

Javascript : What are the different conditions when javascript work in IE but not in Firefox or some other browser?

one that i know of is that while using certain window events..

What other scenarios can cause javascript to not work properly?

Comment: Um, there are whole libraries that are written around differences...

Comment: _"...or some other browser"_ - There are many, many, many other browsers. Nobody has cataloged the differences between all of them. Even just within IE there are differences depending on the version, the document mode, etc.

Comment: This is an hard list to do. Because you want someting that works in IE but not in FF. Generally we develop BEFORE in FF (or Chrome or some other Browser with a decent console) and AFTER in IE :) So maybe I can you say what works in FF and not in IE :).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is too complex to fully list here. Use sites like http://caniuse.com that will tell you which JavaScript is available in which browser.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, all browsers implement JavaScript differently. Microsoft have long been stuck in their own world, implementing their own ways to do things, whereas everyone else seems to try and conform to the standards as much as possible. Microsoft are coming around to the "standards" way of doing things, and from what I hear, IE11 will be a massive step in this direction.

As already mentioned, you can use http://caniuse.com/ to find what you can and can't do in different browsers, but then you'll likely end up doing what many others have done...write your own API which works around these to achieve a task...which is a bit unnecessary, unless you can find a ground-breaking way to implement your API that will be beneficial to other developers.

APIs like jQuery already work around these differences. The aim with these libraries is to provide clean JavaScript, whilst being completely transparent from the underlying JavaScript implementation.

Also, look into "shim"/"polyfill" implementations. These are used when a core feature that is recognised as part of an ECMAScript version has not been implemented in the browser. These provide the implementation for you, if it is not natively supported.